# ActionBar is hiding when keyboard appears

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm using ActionBarSherlock. `windowSoftInputMode` is `adjustPan` (I've tried with `adjustResize` and `adjustNothing` also).

I want to keep `ActionBar` on screen when keyboard appears **but** slide my layout instead (so text remains visible).

Here is how it looks right:
[image]

And when keyboard is appeared:
[image]

**Question is**: how can I keep `ActionBar` visible while using `adjustPan` (so `EditText`s will always be visible)?

**NOTE**
I can't use `ScrollView` to hold my `View`

Comment: @KuangYuang check out the accepted answer

Comment: For adjustResize, it's good and helpful; however, for adjustPan, it does not help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find out, that there may be problems with `adjustResize` (for some reason it's just uses `adjustPan` instead) when you applying `FLAG_FULLSCREEN` to `Window` of `Activity`:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Without this line resizing working just fine.

Comment: Hi, Im facing the same problem, how it should be used? I didnt get :)

Comment: that was really painfull line of code.Wasted my couple of hours.Without this line resizing works fine

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the layout slides up to make some space for the keyborad try:

add this to your manifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard" />
```

the important part is:
**android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard"**

[android documentation manifest.xml](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)