# keyboard hides actionbar while using adjustPan

Tags: android-layout, android

I have a chat which is "mixed", the editText and send button is in java / native and my chat system is in a server and I load it inside of a webview.

I would like to adjust my webview with my keyboard when the user starts typing. I used adjustPan for that and works, but now my actionbar somehow is hidden when the keyboard is open.

Here is part of my android manifest for my Activity:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
    </activity>
```

Here is my chat.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/llFooter">
</WebView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@id/llFooter"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/chat_message"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.9"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:hint="Schreibe deine Nachricht hier..">
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/chat_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:text=">">
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Note: my chat is a fragment

Anyone has an idea how can I fix it?

I already checked these links without success:

[ActionBar is hiding when keyboard appears](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13561459/3350765)

[Soft Keyboard Hiding ActionBar while using adjustPan](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24258256/3350765)

**EDIT 1: SCREENSHOTS ADDED**

AdjustPan: The actionbar is hidden but the chat webview fits with the keyboard
AdjustResize: The actionbar is not hidden but the chat webview doesnt fit. Should scroll down until the last messages

[image: With AdjustPan]

[image: With AdjustResize]

Comment: `adjustPan` will move your application's window to prevent the focused view from being obscured by the keyboard. This includes the ActionBar. What happens when you use `adjustResize` instead?

Comment: @Karakuri I added the screenshots for both cases.

Comment: @Lara I am facing the same problem..Have you found the solution? If yes, please share your answer ....