# Scrollable layout when keyboard pops up, but without focus change

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a UX problem with my layout. I want that is possible that the user can scroll over the compleat layout without a focus change when the keyboard popes up.

This is what the Layout looks like when the activity starts

[image: This is what the Layout looks like when the activity starts]

This is what happens when the user clicks to the Big Text EditText

[image]

This is what I want the layout to look like, the positions should stand in the same way as before, but it should be possible to scroll to the bottom with the keyboard open

[image]

The rootView of my layout is

`<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">`

I also try to add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` and `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` the the activity in the Manifest.xml but it does not solve my problem.

Comment: Try to use this solution hope it will fix your problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25892331/keyboard-hides-actionbar-while-using-adjustpan/54288572#54288572

Comment: it does not work for me